# XML file conversion to database table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I need to convert XML files to tables in Microsoft SQL Server. How do we convert the URLs in XML files to table data?

Comment: Please provide any example of your xml

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you:

```
DECLARE @xmls TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Data XML
)

DECLARE @namespaces TABLE
(
    IdXml INT
,   NamespaceVal XML
)


INSERT INTO @xmls
(
    Data 
)
SELECT 
'
<x:parent xmlns:x="http://temp.temp.org/x/x/" xmlns:y="http://temp.temp.org/y/y/" xmlns:z="http://temp.temp.org/z/z/">
    <z:child1>
        <val>zzz</val>
    </z:child1>
    <y:child2>
        <val>yyy</val>
    </y:child2>
    <x:child3>
        <val>zzz</val>
    </x:child3>
</x:parent>
'

INSERT  INTO @namespaces
(
    IdXml,NamespaceVal 
)


SELECT    t.id,
          t.Data.query('
             for $node in /descendant::node()[namespace-uri() != ""] 
             return <namespace>{ namespace-uri($node) }</namespace>'
                    ) AS nodes
FROM      @xmls t


SELECT  --DISTINCT
        x.IdXml
    ,   na.na.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') namespace
FROM    @namespaces x
        CROSS APPLY x.NamespaceVal.nodes('/') AS n(n)
        CROSS APPLY n.n.nodes('./namespace') AS na(na)
```